# Import excel file to database using Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, excel-import

why get undefined offset when importing excel file to the database using laravel.

***UserImport.php***

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    var_dump($row);
    
    return new User([
        'name' =>$row[0],
        'email'=>$row[1],
        'password' => Hash::make('password'),

    ]);
}
```

***UserImportController***

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $file = $request->file('file');
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, $file);
    return back()->withStatus('Successfully');
}
```

when uploading the excel file, display it like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnSw4.jpg)

I used var_dump() to see the array. I entered 4 rows in the excel file. But display 5 array data. Why that??? (display in entered image.
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set if condition for ***UserImport.php***

```
if($row[0] !=""){ 
    return new User([ 
        'name' =>$row[0], 
        'email'=>$row[1], 
        'password' => Hash::make('password'), 
   ]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because of the new line at the end of the file.

You should check if it contains only a new line and skip the import.

Comment: I added if condition to UserImport.php
if($row[0] !=""){
            return new User([

                'name' =>$row[0],
                'email'=>$row[1],
                'password' => Hash::make('password'),
               
            ]);
        }